# Custom Shadow Color for Paper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, next.js

Is there a way to change only the box-shadow color for mui Paper component. I made my background black so it's shadow is not visible

I've used

```
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
     MuiPaper: {
       root: {
        boxShadow: "0 1px 6px 1px blue"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

as you can see when I give that boxShadow setting every elevation from 0 to 24 uses it

What I need is a way to change just the shadow color, thanks for your help

Comment: did you found a solution please ?

Comment: no, still hoping. what I was able to do was to make it light or dark nothing else

Comment: Related, unsolved still: 
--
Make the shadow color customizable · Issue #11386 · mui/material-ui
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/11386
--
Customize color shadow by property or variant · Issue #30869 · mui/material-ui
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30869

Answer (score 2):

You can change the shadow color , but for a specific elevate you will need to change values if you are using sass or css to over ride , using withStyle you can do it like this

Refer this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-platform-kemqg?file=/src/App.js:0-682

```
import "./styles.css";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: theme.spacing(16),
      height: theme.spacing(16),
      boxShadow:
        "0px 3px 1px -2px red,0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(100,0,0,0.9),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper elevation={2} />
      <Paper elevation={4} />
      <Paper elevation={3} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: nice answer but you'll have to keep do this for all components and it would alter the use of elevation

Comment: material ui use elevation for each elevation value different class like elevate0 , elevate1 , rather than that we can use scss global to overridethe specific elevate or all elevate